# Подсчет кликов

Tags: jquery, php

Добрый день!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".click_tweet").click(function () {
        $("#counter").html(+$("#counter").html() + 1);
    });
});
```

+ jQuery

При нажатии на ссылку с классом `click_tweet12`, ид - counter на основе скрипта подсчитывает клики. И выводит в div, но минус в том, что див *динамичный. Это число в диве не увидеть php методами. Помогите идентифицировать число в дивах. Пожалуйста!
Хочу чтобы при нажатии на ссылку срабатывало условие if.

Comment: Что за "условие if" и что вы понимаете под словом "идентифицировать"?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".click_tweet").click(function () {
        $("#counter").html(+$("#counter").html() + 1);
    });
});
+ jQuery
```

Эм, а это разве не JQuery?

PHP и JS Разные вещи! Могут работать совместно!

```
var str=$("#BAR").val(); // это если из текстового поля
 $.get('ajax/get.php', { bar: str }, function(data) {
// получаем данные в данном случае они переданы в JSON т.к. в php скрипте стоит 
// echo json_encode($value); 
                     var data_mas = eval('('+data+')');
                     });
```

Получаем значение с помощью Jquery и отправляем данные скрипту!

Ну раз ты работаешь с jquery ты должен знать как обратиться к какому-нибудь эл-ту на странице.

```
$(".click_tweet") // по слассу 
$("#BAR") // по ID
```

В твоем случае по классу

```
$("#counter").text();
```

получишь свое значение, ну а потом его отправляешь скрипту php, который разберет переданные ему параметры и обновит БД.

код писать не буду, нужно головой думать иногда! Там же все просто

Comment: Я в этом деле не очень, поэтому и прошу помощи. 
Зачем #BAR и каким я образом выведу статическое число?
Что делать с get.php - как помнится это имя файла в котором размещен данный скрипт?